# write a dataframe to a CSV

Tags: r, csv

Dput: This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
  list(structure(list(date_start = c("2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18"), date_stop = c("2016-12-17", 
"2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
"2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
"2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
"2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
"2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17"), impressions = c("623631", 
"1209005", "508541", "763007", "946022", "2383568", "540094", 
"1254584", "3191299", "4190801", "2359474", "2575801", "70282", 
"183058", "730293", "1480338", "355839", "1669711", "1404607", 
"1987509", "305249", "2170586", "5367446", "4348979", "409597"
), spend = c(34486.51, 88862.98, 32249.5, 76337.45, 50648.22, 
196258.1, 35084.39, 113426.58, 117047.22, 271978.4, 495136.59, 
1808433.13, 4998.89, 45060.97, 21313.06, 120083.89, 15842.37, 
142180.86, 57878.86, 166189.26, 10462.05, 152238.98, 482840.37, 
718257.29, 29674.91), account_id = c("880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
"880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984"), campaign_id = c("6057756544100", 
"6057756544100", "6057559580700", "6057559580700", "6057364739900", 
"6057364739900", "6057310879700", "6057310879700", "6057308793900", 
"6057308793900", "6057235101900", "6057235101900", "6057211751300", 
"6057211751300", "6057176340100", "6057176340100", "6057174959500", 
"6057174959500", "6056810791300", "6056810791300", "6056809420900", 
"6056809420900", "6056722317300", "6056722004900", "6056615572700"
), device_platform = c("desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", 
"desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", 
"desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", 
"desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", 
"mobile", "mobile", "desktop")), .Names = c("date_start", "date_stop", 
"impressions", "spend", "account_id", "campaign_id", "device_platform"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 25L)), structure(list(
    date_start = c("2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
    "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", 
    "2016-11-18"), date_stop = c("2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
    "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", 
    "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17"), impressions = c("1395054", "46582", 
    "384396", "4913690", "6829346", "3099996", "10362788", "501953", 
    "2004573"), spend = c(121206.88, 2884.55, 25574.57, 258769.07, 
    613721.98, 95262.81, 512381.86, 24024.67, 98838.29), account_id = c("880218078740984", 
    "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
    "880218078740984", "880218078740984", "880218078740984", 
    "880218078740984", "880218078740984"), campaign_id = c("6056615572700", 
    "6056341249700", "6056341249700", "6056331814900", "6056331814900", 
    "6056207498100", "6056207498100", "6056205799700", "6056205799700"
    ), device_platform = c("mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "desktop", 
    "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile")), .Names = c("date_start", 
"date_stop", "impressions", "spend", "account_id", "campaign_id", 
"device_platform"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 9L
)))
```

I am trying to write it to a file using write.table function

```
write.table(get(fileName), paste0("/home/rstudio/", fileName) , sep="," , append=TRUE, na = "NA", row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

I get this error on trying to write it in file:

Error in data.frame(list(date_start = c("2016-11-18", "2016-11-18", "2016-11-18",  : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 9

Comment: (1) How do you call write.csv? (2) use dput to publish your argument, so that we'll be able to reproduce it.

Comment: write.table(get(fileName), paste0("/home/rstudio/", fileName) , sep="," , append=TRUE, na = "NA", row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

Comment: (1) please add this into the text of your message

Comment: downvoted, this question is incomprehendable.

Comment: @user31264: Even the smalled output of dput crosses the wordliimit. Any alternative?

Comment: @robert_hilton - make a smaller example which still produces the error.

Comment: @user31264: Please check the update

Comment: +1. I don't know what the question looked like at first, but I appreciate that you took the comments on board to improve it, and now it looks like a reasonable question to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're trying to write a *list of two dataframes* as a .csv file, **not** a dataframe. You have several possible approaches to fixing this.

1. Write two separate .csv files, one for each dataframe - for example, if we call the list defined in your question the_list:

   ```
   write.csv(the_list[[1]], "file1.csv")  # write.table as in your question is also fine
   write.csv(the_list[[2]], "file2.csv")
   ```
2. Since both dataframes have the same column names, you could store them in the same file, either as one dataframe, or as one dataframe immediately below the other.

   ```
   # Convert to one dataframe, then write a .csv file
   the_list[[1]][nrow(the_list[[1]]) + 1:nrow(the_list[[2]]), ] <- the_list[[2]]
   write.csv(the_list[[1]], "filename.csv")

   # Append the second file below the first
   # There will be column names separating the two tables
   # unless you set col.names=F for the second write.table
   # Appending column names may produce a warning, but that's ok if it's what you want
   write.table(the_list[[1]], "filename.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
   write.table(the_list[[2]], "filename.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
   ```

There are other ways you could try joining the dataframes before you write them to one file, such as adding rows containing only `NA` at the bottom of the shorter dataframe, then using `cbind`, or equivalent. In some contexts, it may make sense to `merge` them etc.